# Strange UDP Packets I can't acount for?

Tags: linux, networking, security

I recently noticed a strange set of UDP packets I can't account for.

**Every 9 seconds I receive a UDP packet from 156.146.58.62 : port 1197** .

The packet is always 41 bytes of binary data, which changes with every packet.

Port 1197 is nominally "*carrius r-shell*" for remote access.

I can't find any useful information about *156.146.58.62* .

I first noticed it because my system was responding with *ICMP Unreachable* messages. I have since black-holed the IP with iptables, so no more ICMP messages.

Although the packet is now being dropped, I can still see that the packet is still arriving every 9 seconds. My machine is behind a NAT, it is not in the DMZ, and there are no router forwarding rules.

**So why/how am I seeing this packet?**

The only thing I can think is that I have some application like Zoom or Skype that's initiating the NAT dynamic port allocation and the 9 second repetition from 156.146.58.62 is holding it open?

Any insights?

Comment: If it's coming to your NAT PC it is almost definitely some sort of UPNP at play - this could be Skype, Zoom or even Bittorrent.

Comment: According to ``whois`` that iP belongs to [DataCamp](https://datacamp.co.uk/) which seems to be a hosting provider in the UK. Does that ring a bell with you?

Comment: @Nils - Nope, I saw that it's a hosting provider but it means nothing to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I found it.

I NMAP'd it and made the connect.

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE    VERSION
80/tcp   open  http?
443/tcp  open  openvpn    OpenVPN
8443/tcp open  https-alt?

No exact OS matches for host
```

**PIA** (*Private Internet Access*) revamped their service structure under new ownership. Their UDP VPN servers generally use port 1197.

I was unable to find a particular server DNS for this IP, but after power cycling my router I no longer see the packet inside the NAT. I haven't checked the router logs.

I suspect this is an old server, possibly overlooked or misconfigured remnant.